# Activities button, Alt-F1, and super not working after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

If I hit the  Activities button, all open applications are hidden. There is no way to get the applications to display again. The application I select is started, and shows up on the vertical bar in the left with an orange dot by it.

What magic is needed to bring the applications back?

They are still there. I see them when I go to log out. Logging out is the only option for restoring Gnome.

The same problem happens if I hit Alt-F1 or Super. Shouldn't these toggle?

Thanks, Andy

Edit:

The only way to get a screen shot it with my phone. Sorry for the quality. You can see on the left that I started gimp.Up to 19.10, when I used "Activities", it would launch the app and then return to my running applications.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at all the workspaces? And, post some screenshots at the Activities screen.

Comment: I can't post screen shots because the only productive thing I can do from this state is log out. I've looked at all workspaces.

Comment: Have you got any error while upgrading tp 20.04? It looks like the upgrade broke something. You can try logging into TTY and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it right after upgrading. I saw some references to multiple keyboard support being a problem. I removed Japanese language support. I still have the problem with only an English keyboard. I used synaptic to reinstall ubuntu-desktop. No change. I rebooted to make sure all changes were in effect.

Comment: This seems to working OK now. I filed a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1890650 My guess is that some packages I removed fixed the problem.